# keyboard erroring on one line but not the other

Tags: python

why does it error on the second keyboard? pycharms does not show the error but it still breaks, vsc and sublime both identify this error

```
import time
import pyautogui
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import random

keyboard = Controller()

start = input("do you want to start: ")

def main():
    print("starting")
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        keyboard.press("w")
        print("holding w")
        time.sleep((random.uniform(0.1, 0.3)
        keyboard.release("w") #error line
        print("released w")


if start == "yes":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please add your error code and text into your post

Answer (score 1):

Your error message is caused by:

```
time.sleep((random.uniform(0.1, 0.3)
```

You are missing "))" at the end to close the brackets.
Change it to:

```
time.sleep((random.uniform(0.1, 0.3)))
```

ADDITIONALLY:
Also I believe it's more common to write

```
keyboard.press('w')
```

instead of

```
keyboard.press("w")
```

Comment: thanks filipA, i’ll be sure to try that when i’m on my computer tomorrow, i also use “” instead of ‘’ since i usually do vb.net and i believe it hasn’t caused any issues so far!